# How can I find font progress on the Google Dev timeline?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

Here is a screens shot.  There are all these 2px lines with color coding.

But where does it explain what the color coding is.

Where is my single Font on this timeline.

How am I supposed to tell?

Answer (score 0):

see https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading#determine-performance-by-resource-type

The overview panel you're talking about is meant to be a way to quickly filter the network resources based on time loaded. Use the timeline column on the left of the network table to see details about specific resources.

EDIT:

Your popped out devtools should look something like this

[image]

The individual timing for each resource is on the right hand side.

Comment: I have no left column.  I popped the dev window out to make it big and I still have no left column.

Comment: I tried scrolling, but no go. The requests took so long.